# What is the English name of these sea snails?

Tags: language, food-identification, seafood, vietnamese-cuisine

What is the English name of sea snails sold in Vietnam that the Vietnamese labelled as Ốc bông & Ốc tỏi (Vietnamese)?
[image]

**Ốc bông**

[image]

**Ốc tỏi**

Comment: What are you asking for? You say whether a plant or animal is edible, but then ask for a translation.

Comment: It is very possible that there is no common English name for something if it isn't familiar to people outside of Vietnam. What is more likely is that there is a *Latin* scientific name for it, and it may be easier to find an English name starting from the Latin rather than the Vietnamese.

Comment: I got a better answer for Ốc tỏi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ốc bông** = **tiger moon snail** ([hotdeal.vn](https://oms.hotdeal.vn/images/editors/sources/000354224183/Menu%20buffet%20200%20-english.pdf), [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=tiger%20moon%20snail&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0yJjSiObiAhVDLFAKHTlHCEoQ_AUIECgB&biw=1280&bih=918)) or in Latin: *Notocochlis tigrina* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notocochlis_tigrina))

**Ốc tỏi** = **Japanese bonnet snail** ([Facebook](https://hi-in.facebook.com/haisantuoisachbienhoa/photos/%E1%BB%90c-t%E1%BB%8Fi-(japanese-bonnet-snail/2103946023184101/), [Wild Fact Sheets](http://www.wildsingapore.com/wildfacts/mollusca/gastropoda/cassidae/bisulcata.htm), [images](http://www.seashellsupply.com/japanese-bonnet-seashells-india-10-pcs-phalium-bisulcatum/), [more images](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=918&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=iAoCXYf0OfCSmwW25b74Cw&q=japanese%20bonnet%20snail&oq=japanese%20bonnet%20snail&gs_l=img.3...44000.44000..44373...0.0..0.69.69.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz-img.eBX5PTJQBt8)) or in Latin: *Semicassis bisulcata* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicassis_bisulcata)). Ốc tỏi is sometimes refered to as "garlic snail" ([Hong Hai](http://www.seafoodhonghai.com/vi/thuc-don/Oc-toi-57/), [Cooky](https://www.cooky.vn/wiki/%E1%BB%91c-t%E1%BB%8Fi)), but this is obviously different from garlic glass snail, which is a land snail ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxychilus_alliarius)).

Here on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/ocsaigonq2/posts/2302892746622786/) are Vietnamese/English translations for more than 100 types of seafood, including Ốc bông and Ốc tỏi.